# Numpad isn't working on Dell Inspiron 1764

Tags: windows-7, windows, keyboard

The numbers on right side of my laptop aren't working. They will work when I log in but after that they don't work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

On laptops (and even desktops!), you often need to have numlock turned on to use the keypad - might be worth checking if its active, and/or if its getting switched off somehow after bootup